# Why is string "11" less than string "3"?

Tags: javascript, string, comparison

```
if ('11' < '3') alert('true');
```

It's obvious that it's not comparing them by length but by encoding instead. However, I don't understand how it works. I need some explanation :-)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Strings are compared [lexicographicaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). i.e. character by character until they are not equal or there aren't any characters left to compare. The first character of '11' is less than the first character of '3'.

```
> '11' < '3'
true
> '31' < '3'
false
> '31' < '32'
true
> '31' < '30'
false
```

If we use letters then, since `b` is not less than `a`, `abc` is not less than `aaa`, but since `c` is less than `d`, `abc` is less than `abd`.

```
> 'abc' < 'aaa'
false
> 'abc' < 'abd'
true
```

You can explicitly convert strings to numbers:

```
> +'11' < '3'
false
```

Comment: Yes. String comparison is done mostly alphabetically.

Comment: Just a quick note: pay attention to the lowercases and uppercases. Uppercases come before lowercases. Ex: `'abc' < 'Abd' //false`

Answer (score 4):

By default, JavaScript will compare two strings by each character's ordinal value; much like how `strcmp()` works in C.

To make your comparison work, you can cast either side to a number to tell the interpreter your intentions of numeric comparison:

```
Number('11') < '3' // false
+'11' < '3' // false, using + to coerce '11' to a numeric

'11' < Number('3') // false
'11' < +'3' // false
```

Answer (score 4):

In Many Programming languages Strings are compared as [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). You can check [Alphabetical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order#Alphabetical_order)

Answer (score 3):

It compares by each character, the following will be `false`:

```
if ('41' < '3') alert('true');
```

Since `4` is not less than `3`. So essentially your comparison boiled down to this:

```
if ('1' < '3') alert('true'); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

`'1' < '3'` and since the first character is the "most significant character" (not that this term makes any sense). Any following characters will not be compared anymore.

Comment: I guess OP might not know ASCII. Therefore, I believe it may be helpful if a sorted list of characters is included. Here is it: [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Answer (score 0):

It has been treated as string comparision. So 1 < 3 (1st chars of two strings) then string 11 preceeds string 3