# Javascript great than and less than not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a set of functions pull an image from the URL. For example if the URL is example.com/image/8/ the 8th image will be loaded.

The problem is that when the URL is less than 10 it doesn't work (and my function sets the varNumber to 1, but when its 10 or more the fuction works fine.  Here is the code..

```
var totalCount = '<?php echo $total; ?>'; 
HREF = '<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>';

var url = window.location.pathname;
var urlsplit = url.split("/");
var imgNumber = urlsplit[5];


if (typeof imgNumber === 'undefined') {
       imgNumber = 1;
 } else if (imgNumber < 1) {
       imgNumber = 1;
       history.pushState('', '', HREF);

 } else if (imgNumber > totalCount) {
       alert("else if ( " + imgNumber + " > " + totalCount + ")");
       imgNumber = 1;
       history.pushState('', '', HREF);

 } else {
    $("#slider-"+imgNumber).removeClass("img-inactive");
    $("#slider-"+imgNumber).addClass("img-active");
    $("#slider-1").removeClass("img-active");
    $("#slider-1").addClass("img-inactive");
 }
```

As you can see the code above first checks to see if the varNumber is defined then checks if its less than 1. After that it checks if it's greater than the totalCount.  This is where it gets messed up. Ive checked my browser console and ran the alerts to to verify the totalCount and imgNumber have variables.

To get a better example see the following links:

imgNumber > totalCount Does not work...
http://badsentinel.com/2014/09/18/daily-giftastic-take-away-these-three-fingers-and-what-are-we-left-with-13-gifs/3/

imgNumber > totalCount works fine...
http://badsentinel.com/2014/09/18/daily-giftastic-take-away-these-three-fingers-and-what-are-we-left-with-13-gifs/10/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Parse the value with `parseInt` as shown :

```
var imgNumber = parseInt(urlsplit[5],10);  //second parameter i.e '10' here is radix which is optional but it is advised to use it.
```

Otherwise in **javascript/jquery** values are treated as `string` when we deal in `numbers` we have to parse it with `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

**EDIT :-** As per your comment try this :

```
var imgNumber = parseInt(urlsplit[5],10) || 0; //if parseInt() fails to parse value to int then it will return 0 value.
```

Comment: The code you gave me worked for that issue..  But now it has created another issue.

Now when I go the root link it is not defining the imgNumber. Can you please tell me what `if (typeof imgNumber === 'undefined') {
       imgNumber = 1;
 }` needs to be changed to. I'm guessing `typeof` is also for a string so would you be able to tell me what it is for an int?  thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much.. Since it was setting the var to zero I had to change the if statement to check if it was set to 0 instead of undefined.    Otherwise it was going into an infinite loop because my code cant have a "0" image. It must be between 1 and the totalcount. Looks like its working now though. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

When grabbing the `imgNumber` do this instead:

```
var imgNumber = parseInt(urlsplit[5]);
```

`urlsplit[5]` will retrieve a `string`, so you need to parse it to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly convert `imgNumber` from the string representation retrieved from `window.location.pathname` to a number prior to comparing it.  When you compare a string value to a numeric literal, the numeric literal is cast to a string rather than the other way around.

See [Why is string "11" less than string "3"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863092/why-is-string-11-less-than-string-3) for clarity on why they're sorting that way.

Answer (score 0):

Change `urlsplit[5];` to `+urlsplit[5];` so it gets cast to a Number. It's a String.