# Understanding why I need parseInt() in that case

Tags: javascript

For a form validation I use a very simple comparism. `If y >= x` then it returns `false`.

I have solved my problem by using `parseInt()`, but I don't understand why I need this function for only ONE value. Eat code:

```
function validateForm() {
        var x = parseInt(document.forms["einstform"]["zeit1"].value);
        var y = parseInt(document.forms["einstform"]["zeit2"].value);
        if (y >= x) {
            alert("Nope." + " " + x + " " + y);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And this is my form for that:

```
<form name="einstform" action="a file" method="GET" onSubmit="return validateForm();">

    <select name="zeit1">
      <option value="30">1 Month</option>
      <option value="60" selected>2 Months</option>
      <option value="90">3 Months</option>
    </select>

    <select name="zeit2">
      <option value="0">Never</option>
      <option value="7">1 Week</option>
      <option value="14" selected>2 Weeks</option>
      <option value="21">3 Weeks</option>
      <option value="30">4 Weeks</option>
      <option value="42">6 Weeks</option>
      <option value="60">8 Weeks</option>
      <option value="84">12 Weeks</option>
    </select>
```

I guess this is simple to understand. It just compares selected values and cancels the form submit when `y >= x`. And it works pretty well, yes. But if I select in the second select "1 Week" (value = 7), the script always tells me 7 >= 30.

Sure, it may get a string value for that `7`, for that I have to use `parseInt()` (and with that it works).

**But why does the int comparism of all other values work perfectly, except for that `7`?**

Is this just random to tell me "always use `parseInt()`" or is there more to understand why a `7` refuses to be an int value?

Comment: If you don't parse the value as integer, then it is interpreted as a string and "7" >= "3"

Comment: Because `.value` is a string. Without `parseInt` you perform a lexicographic comparison, not a mathematical one

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863092/why-is-string-11-less-than-string-3

Comment: @wye I read your answer and it totally fits to my question. Sorry that I didn't found that answer before (didn't thought of a lexicographic comparism, my bad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't parse the value with `parseInt()`, it's a string.

Else you get a `string >= string`

Now it is `7 >= 3` instead

Comment: So it was just luck that all not-7s worked, because their alphabetical order come first?

Comment: It's because if you  use string instead it checks the characters with each other.

Comment: I read the related answer and it totally fits. Yup, I understand now. Thanks, you saved me a bunch of money for a sanitorium.