# Why do JavaScript comparisons have different results for strings and for numbers?

Tags: javascript

I simply cannot wrap my head around this:

```
2590.00 > 2.00 //== true  
"2590.00" > "2.00" //== true  
105.00 > 2.00 //== true  
"105.00" > "2.00" //== false???
```

Why is the last expression returning `false`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863092/why-is-string-11-less-than-string-3

Comment: Because it's considered as a string, so it'll compare character by character, and the "1" is < than "2" , so when we compare with > , we'll get false as a result.

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"105.00" > "2.00"
```

is comparing **strings** instead of **numbers**.

Comment: I get that, but then why does    "2590.00" > "2.00" //== true?

Comment: @stark102088 because they are string

Comment: Ok so...."2590.00" > "2.00" returns true and they are strings... "105.00" > "2.00" returns false and they are strings...

Comment: @stark102088, check string comparisons... it checks symbol by symbol, so '9' is more than '88888888888888888', cause it checks first letter and '9' > '8', thus 'true' is returned.

Comment: As the first character in both the cases is `2`. It goes to the next char. ASCII value of `5 is 53` and `. is 46` --- So `53 > 46` which is true.

Comment: This is such a terrible answer, I don't know why @stark102088 accepted it. It does nothing more than state what he obviously already knew.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing two strings, "2.00" will be greater than "105.00", because (alphabetically) 105.00 is less than 2.00.

> When comparing a string with a numeric constant, JavaScript will treat
>   the number as a string when doing the comparison. The result of this
>   is commonly not the same as a numeric comparison.
>   To secure a proper result, variables should be converted to the proper
>   type before comparison:

Parse the string into an integer using parseInt:

```
javascript:alert(parseInt("105.00")>parseInt("2.00"));
```

Comment: This answer is the only half-way decent one, but you're quoted a source without giving credit. Please update your answer so you're not plagiarizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
"105.00" > "2.00"
```

is comparing the strings `"105.00"`and `"2.00"` and since `'1' < '2'` it returns `false`

Comment: perfect this is what I was looking for - it goes character by character and compares those

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because JS compare signs of string ("1" < "2" etc) instead of numbers.