# Check if input is between two values (multiple conditions)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am making a project where I need to read in numbers that can be in different format and check these against the users input. In some cases this will be an intervall like "8800-9000", in some cases it will be a 4-digit number, in some cases a 5-digit number.

The array looks like this:

```
var testArray = [
{
    "label": "Nordea",
    "value": ["1100-1199", "1400-2099", "3000-3399", "3410-4999"]
},
{
    "label": "Swedbank",
    "value": ["7000-7120", "7123-8104", "8106-8999"]
},
{
    "label": "Sparbanken Nord",
    "value": "8264"
},
{
    "label": "Sparbanken i Enköping",
    "value": ["7121-7122", "8305-5"]
}];
```

I've made a huge nested if-mess that works kind of OK. My only issue is that its not breaking when it finds a match. If i input "8305-5" it will find a match in 2 different object property arrays. Have I designed the "between"-function wrong?

Also I can search for numbers that are way bigger than the intervalls and still get a match. Intervall "3410 - 3999" is in an array, and if I search for "39999" it will still get a match.

All help much appreciated!

I iterate over all objects in the array, and if the value-property is an array I will check the lenght of each element to see if I should match a "between"-value or a straight "===" match.

If its not an array I try a simple match.

```
function searchForClearing() {

  var userInput = document.getElementById("clearingnummerTextBox").value;

  for (var i in testArray) {
    var currentObject = testArray[i];

    if (Array.isArray(currentObject.value)) {

      for (i = 0; i < currentObject.value.length; i++) {

        if (currentObject.value[i].length === 9) {

          var firstInterval = currentObject.value[i].split('-')[0];

          var lastInterval = currentObject.value[i].split('-')[1];

          if (userInput >= firstInterval && userInput <= lastInterval) {
            console.log("Inmatat: " + userInput + " " + "Träff på: " + currentObject.value);
            document.getElementById("bankResult").innerHTML = currentObject.label;
            console.log("Sökte mellan intervallen: " + firstInterval + " - " + lastInterval);

            console.log("9 teckens sök");
          }

        } else if (currentObject.value[i].length === 6) {

          if (userInput == currentObject.value[i]) {
            console.log("Inmatat: " + userInput + " " + "Träff på: " + currentObject.value);
            document.getElementById("bankResult").innerHTML = currentObject.label;
            console.log("Sökte mellan intervallen: " + firstInterval + " - " + lastInterval);
            console.log("6 teckens sök");
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (currentObject.value.length === 9) {

        var firstInterval = currentObject.value.split('-')[0];
        var lastInterval = currentObject.value.split('-')[1];

        if (userInput >= firstInterval && userInput <= lastInterval) {
          console.log("Inmatat: " + userInput + " " + "Träff på: " + currentObject.label);
          document.getElementById("bankResult").innerHTML = currentObject.label;
          console.log("Sökte mellan intervallen: " + firstInterval + " - " + lastInterval);
          return true;
        }

      } else if (currentObject.value.length === 4) {

        if (userInput == currentObject.value) {
          console.log("Träff på clearingnummer som inte var i en array: " + userInput + " " + currentObject.label);
          document.getElementById("bankResult").innerHTML = currentObject.label;
          return true;
        }

      }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you have "39999" return `true` even though its out-of-range is because strings in JS are compared [lexographically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863114/3928341).

```
"39999" < "4999" // true
 39999  <  4999  // false
```

You need to converted the strings to numbers using something like [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) before doing the comparison.

As far as reducing some of the nested `if` mess, your two best friends for this example are [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Both `find` and `some` iterate over an array calling a function for every element.

- `find`: If that function returns `true`, `find` stops iterating and returns the current element. You can use it to find an object within your `testArray` whose `value` is equal to the user input or contains it in a range.
- `some`: If that function returns `true`, `some` stops iterating and returns `true` as well. You can use it when the `testArray` value is an array to check if user input is within at least one of the ranges. We use `some` instead of another `find` because we only want to check if something is contained in an array and we don't care to actually get it back.

Here's how you can write your function using `find` and `some`:

```
function findTestObject(input) {

  // iterate over the test array and 
  // stop as soon we found a match 
  // (as the passed function returns true)
  return testArray.find(function (testObj) {
    var value = testObj.value;

    // if current value is an array of ranges
    // check if userInput is within at least one of the ranges
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return value.some(function (range) {
        // split the current range into min and max and compare with user input
        var rangeData = range.split('-');
        return parseInt(rangeData[0]) <= input && input <= parseInt(rangeData[1]);
      });
    } 
    // otherwise do a direct comparison
    else {
      return value === input;
    }
  });
}
```

This function will either return the first object from `testArray` whose value matches user input, or `undefined`.

Here's a full example:

```js
var testArray = [{
  "label": "Nordea",
  "value": ["1100-1199", "1400-2099", "3000-3399", "3410-4999"]
}, {
  "label": "Swedbank",
  "value": ["7000-7120", "7123-8104", "8106-8999"]
}, {
  "label": "Sparbanken Nord",
  "value": "8264"
}, {
  "label": "Sparbanken i Enköping",
  "value": ["7121-7122", "8305-5"]
}];

function findTestObject(input) {
  return testArray.find(function (testObj) {
    var value = testObj.value;

    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return value.some(function (range) {
        var rangeData = range.split('-');
        return parseInt(rangeData[0]) <= input && input <= parseInt(rangeData[1]);
      });
    } else {
      return value === input;
    }
  });
}

function test() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var result = findTestObject(userInput);
  var label = result ? result.label : 'Not Found';
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = label;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="Enter something..."/>
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
<br />
Result: <div id="result"></div>
```

*Note*: You have an inconsistency in your example. All the ranges are in increasing order (min, max) except in the last array, where you have `"8305-5"`.
With the code above, this range will never return true.

One way you can solve this is to always sort the range array in ascending order before comparing.

```
var rangeData = range.split('-').sort();
```

See [How to correctly sort array of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly) for examples and gotchas.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer! This explains a lot to me. Im coming from C# so a loosely typed language is really new to me.

Comment: The last example "8305-5" is a real value, and this is one of my issues. I have to check the user input against this value aswell. I made a check that checks if the length of the element is "6" which seems to work.

Comment: You're welcome mate :). As far as the 8305-5 part, if you cannot change the data you're receiving, instead of checking a hardcoded length value, you could call `range.split('-').sort()` to always sort the min/max values in ascending order before comparing, that way it will be more generic. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly) for examples