# Check if input is same value (multiple conditions) javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, search

I need to search the value of each label , for any number match the user input 
if user input same as any number of the value , it shows the label , the code below is for showing result if input match the range between two numbers which I don't want

```js
var testArray = [{
  "label": "Nordea",
  "value": ["77038-3532 - 19428 - 18073 - 08028 - 07058 - 07936 - 77038 - 3532 "]
}, {
  "label": "Swedbank",
  "value": ["77038-3532 - 19428 - 18073 - 08028 - 07058 - 07936 - 77038 - 3532 "]
}, {
  "label": "Sparbanken Nord",
  "value": "8264"
}, {
  "label": "Sparbanken i Enköping",
  "value": ["7121-7122", "8305-5"]
}];

function findTestObject(input) {
  return testArray.find(function (testObj) {
    var value = testObj.value;

    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return value.some(function (range) {
        var rangeData = range.split('-');
        return parseInt(rangeData[0]) <= input && input <= parseInt(rangeData[1]);
      });
    } else {
      return value === input;
    }
  });
}

function test() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var result = findTestObject(userInput);
  var label = result ? result.label : 'Not Found';
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = label;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="Enter something..."/>
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
<br />
Result: <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I got the code above from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140929/check-if-input-is-between-two-values-multiple-conditions

Comment: So user will enter this complete string `77038-3532 - 19428 - 18073 - 08028 - 07058 - 07936 - 77038 - 3532` in input?

Comment: no , only one number , for example 07058  or 19428

Comment: First question: what have you tried yourself?  That's an important part of questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Second one: how are your `values` supposed to be organized?  I can make little sense out of the examples.  Some things look like ranges, others like single values, and still others like parts numbers including a hyphen.  One is not even an array, but a single string.  What format(s) can we expect?  What do they mean?  Are there ranges, for instance.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I tried different things , couldn't solve the issue , I am no developer is just a hobby  , it is simple search , for example you put the zip code of a city it shows you which nearest sea port or airport ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is using `match`, because I think it's easier to deal with different types of data stored in value.

```js
function findTestObject(input) {

var testArray = [{
    "label": "Nordea",
    "value": ["77038-3532 - 19428 - 18073 - 08028 - 07058 - 07936 - 77038 - 3532 "]
  },
     {
    "label": "Sparbanken Nord",
    "value": "8264"
  }, {
    "label": "Sparbanken i Enköping",
    "value": ["7121-7122", "8305-5"]
  }];

  var r = new RegExp(input, "gi");

  var result = [];

  testArray.forEach(e=>{
    if (e.value.toString().match(r)) {
        result.push(e.label);
      }
  })

  return result;
}

function test() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var result = findTestObject(userInput);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (result.join(" ") || "Not Found");
}
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="Enter something..." />
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
<br /> Result:
<div id="result"></div>
```

I'm not considering if user put an `-`, that match several values, but it's good as example, you could exclude it easily.

Comment: that is correct , but is it possible to remove this , {
    "label": "Swedbank",
    "value": ["77038-3532 - 19428 - 18073 - 08028 - 07058 - 07936 - 77038 - 3532 "]
  },

Comment: and the results appear without (and)

Comment: @J.Ali it's possible, I've updated the answer, I've added "and" because maybe you need something to differentiate the results.

Comment: thank you ,, is it possible to add the error message if there is no results

Comment: @J.Ali sure, I've added the "Not found"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this should be what you are looking for:

```js
var testArray = [{
  "label": "Nordea",
  "value": ["77038-3532 - 19428 - 18073 - 08028 - 07058 - 07936 - 77038 - 3532 "]
}, {
  "label": "Swedbank",
  "value": ["77038-3532 - 19428 - 18073 - 08028 - 07058 - 07936 - 77038 - 3532 "]
}, {
  "label": "Sparbanken Nord",
  "value": "8264"
}, {
  "label": "Sparbanken i Enköping",
  "value": ["7121-7122", "8305-5"]
}];

function findTestObject(input) {
  return testArray.find(function (testObj) {
    var value = testObj.value;

    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return value.some(function (range) {
        return parseInt(range === input);
      });
    } else {
      return value === input;
    }
  });
}

function test() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var result = findTestObject(userInput);
  var label = result ? result.label : 'Not Found';
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = label;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" placeholder="Enter something..."/>
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
<br />
Result: <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: try search for any of these numbers 19428 - 18073 - 08028 - 07058 - 07936 - 77038 - 3532              ) in Nordea label , it shows not found

Comment: @J.Ali in that case I didn't fully understand your question. You want the text "Nordea" to appear when one of those numbers is entered?

Comment: Also please note that your data model isn't consistent, in the case of Sparbanken Nord, the value is of type string, in other cases it is array.

Comment: yes even after removing Sparbanken  , still same issue