# javascript onchange get return

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

i have 3 input like this

Grand Total Box

```
<input type="text" name="GrandTotal" id="GrandTotal" class=" form-control" placeholder="Grand Total"  required />
```

Down Payment

```
<input type="text" name="DownPayment" id="downpayment" class=" form-control" placeholder="Down Payment" required />
```

Status Box

```
 <input type="text" name="Status" id="status" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
```

So the Grand Total input is automatically filled using javascript, 
example GrandTotal is **2500**, then i had to fill the downpayment box, when i input downpayment like **3000**, the status must say **PAID OFF**. but when we fill the downpayment like **2000** status must say **MINUS 500**

but the reality is when i write the downpayment just number **5** it say **PAID OFF** and didnt change even i put more than the grandtotal's value. but when i delete the value it say undefined

here's my script

```
$('#downpayment').on('keyup keydown', function (
       var $this = $(this),
            GrandTotal = $("#GrandTotal").val(),
            downpayment = $("#downpayment").val();
          var  value = GrandTotal - downpayment;

            if (GrandTotal < downpaymentval) {
              var status = "PAID OFF";
            $('#status').val(status);
            } else {
              var status = "MINUS".value;
            $('#status').val(status);
            }
            console.log(status);

    });
```

Thanks, now it solved, thankyou for answering

Comment: In addition to Kaddath, see this to understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863092/why-is-string-11-less-than-string-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some typo in your code. I added some `parseFloat` when you get the numbers and emptied the `status` field.

```js
$("#downpayment").on("keyup keydown", function () {
    var $this       = $(this),
        GrandTotal  = parseFloat($("#GrandTotal").val()),
        downpayment = parseFloat($("#downpayment").val());

    // Empty status field
    $("#status").val("");

    // Returns if undefined
    if (!downpayment || !GrandTotal) {
        return;
    }

    // Your code
    var value = GrandTotal - downpayment;

    if (GrandTotal < downpayment) {
        var status = "PAID OFF";
        $("#status").val(status);
    } else {
        var status = "MINUS " + value;
        $("#status").val(status);
    }

    console.log(status);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="GrandTotal" id="GrandTotal" class=" form-control" placeholder="Grand Total" required />
<input type="text" name="DownPayment" id="downpayment" class=" form-control" placeholder="Down Payment" required />
<input type="text" name="Status" id="status" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string to float before you can compare them.
This can be done using `parseFloat`

```
GrandTotal = parseFloat($("#GrandTotal").val());
downpayment = parseFloat($("#downpayment").val());
```

Refer jsFiddle [here](http://GrandTotal%20=%20parseFloat($(%22#GrandTotal%22).val());%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20downpayment%20=%20parseFloat($(%22#downpayment%22).val());)

Answer (score 0):

I have created the solution for the problem,

```
<input type="text" name="GrandTotal" id="GrandTotal" class=" form-control" placeholder="Grand Total"  required />
    <input type="text" name="DownPayment" id="downpayment" class=" form-control" placeholder="Down Payment" required />
    <input type="text" name="Status" id="status" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#downpayment').on('keyup keydown', function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var GrandTotal = parseInt($("#GrandTotal").val());
            var downpayment = parseInt($("#downpayment").val());
            var value = GrandTotal - downpayment;
            if (GrandTotal <= downpayment) {
                var status = "PAID OFF";
                $('#status').val(status);
            } else {
                var status = "MINUS" + value;
                $('#status').val(status);
            }
            console.log(status);
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `downpaymentval` but that variable isn't in the code you've shown. Should it be `value` instead?

You have also used a dot to concatenate a string instead of an addition sign.

Try the following:

```
$('#downpayment').on('keyup keydown', function (
   var $this = $(this), status,
        GrandTotal = $("#GrandTotal").val(),
        downpayment = $("#downpayment").val(),
        value = GrandTotal - downpayment;

        if (GrandTotal < value) {
          status = "PAID OFF";
        $('#status').val(status);
        } else {
          status = "MINUS" + value;
        $('#status').val(status);
        }
        console.log(status);

});
```

You will also notice that I've moved the declaration of the `status` variable to the top. JavaScript doesn't change scope inside if/else statements, so you shouldn't be declaring it twice.

Answer (score 0):

try parsing the numeric values as .val() gives a string object.

```
$('#downpayment').on('keyup keydown', function (
       var $this = $(this),
            GrandTotal = $("#GrandTotal").val(),
            downpayment = $("#downpayment").val();
          var  value = GrandTotal - downpayment;

            if (parseInt(GrandTotal) < parseInt(downpaymentval)) {
              var status = "PAID OFF";
            $('#status').val(status);
            } else {
              var status = "MINUS".value;
            $('#status').val(status);
            }
            console.log(status);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of errors on your code. See the updated code below.

```html
<input type="number" name="GrandTotal" id="GrandTotal" class=" form-control" placeholder="Grand Total"  required />
  <input type="number" name="DownPayment" id="downpayment" class=" form-control" placeholder="Down Payment" required />
  <input type="text" name="Status" id="status" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $('#downpayment').on('keyup keydown', function (){
   
         var $this = $(this),
              GrandTotal = $("#GrandTotal").val(),
              downpayment = $("#downpayment").val();
            var  value = GrandTotal - downpayment;
            var status = '';
              if (GrandTotal < downpayment) {
                status = "PAID OFF";            
              } else {
                status = "MINUS" + value;           
              }
              $('#status').val(status);
              console.log(status);

      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code. Change

**1.**  `var status = "MINUS".value;` to `var status = "MINUS" + value;`.

**2.**  `$('#downpayment').on('keyup keydown', function (` to `$('#downpayment').on('keyup keydown', function () {`

**Updated code**

```js
$('#downpayment').on('change', function() {
  var GrandTotal = $("#GrandTotal").val(),
    downpayment = $("#downpayment").val();
  var value = GrandTotal - downpayment;

  if (GrandTotal <= downpayment) {
    var status = "PAID OFF";
    $('#status').val(status);
  } else {
    var status = "MINUS " + value;
    $('#status').val(status);
  }
  console.log(GrandTotal,downpayment,status);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="GrandTotal" id="GrandTotal" class=" form-control" placeholder="Grand Total" required />
<input type="text" name="DownPayment" id="downpayment" class=" form-control" placeholder="Down Payment" required />
<input type="text" name="Status" id="status" class="form-control" placeholder="Status">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
$('#downpayment').on('keyup keydown', function (){
var $this = $(this),
GrandTotal = parseFloat($("#GrandTotal").val()),
downpayment = parseFloat($("#downpayment").val());
var value = GrandTotal - downpayment;
var status = '';

if (GrandTotal < downpayment) {
  status = "PAID OFF";
} else {
  status = "MINUS " + value;
}

$('#status').val(status);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#downpayment').on('keyup', function (){
        var grandTotal = $("#GrandTotal").val();
        var downpayment = $("#downpayment").val();
        grandTotal = grandTotal == undefined || grandTotal.length == 0?0:parseFloat(grandTotal);
        downpayment = downpayment == undefined || downpayment.length == 0?0:parseFloat(downpayment);
        var  value = grandTotal - downpayment;
        var status = value<0?"PAID OFF":"MINUS " + value;
        $('#status').val(status);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot many errors in your code. Undefined variable, You haven't converted the value to an integer. 
Here I have solved.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMEazW

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#downpayment').on('keydown', function () {
        GrandTotal = $("#GrandTotal").val();
        downpayment = $("#downpayment").val();
        GrandTotal = parseInt(GrandTotal);
        downpayment = parseInt(downpayment);
        var  value = parseInt(GrandTotal) - parseInt(downpayment);      
        var status = '';
        if (GrandTotal < downpayment) {
            status = "PAID OFF";
            $('#status').val(status);              
        } else {
            status = "MINUS " + value;            
            $('#status').val(status);
        }
    console.log(status);
});
```

});