# how to calculate max value of a data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get max value from all 'value' property. Following code giving max value as 8, where as max value in data is 60.

How to get correct maximum value for the following data?

```js
data = [
        { type: "type1", value: "60" },
        { type: "type2", value: "38" },
        { type: "type3", value: "4" },
        { type: "type4", value: "5" },
        { type: "type5", value: "8" },
        { type: "type6", value: "2" },
      ];
      console.log(
        d3.max(data, (d) => {
          return d.value;
        })
      );// expecting 60 but getting 8
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you need to change your values to ints and then compare them. Right now youre comparing strings

Comment: `Math.max(...data.map(({value}) => value))`

Comment: @MoritzRoessler Strings are compared lexicographicaly. The first chars in the strings are compared, so in this case 4, 5, and 8 would be bigger than 38. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863092/why-is-string-11-less-than-string-3

Comment: @Craicerjack That's obviously right. I don't know what i was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

A simple one liner suffices. `Math.max(...data.map(({value}) => +value))`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to turn those values into actual numbers. Or if you need them into a string, you can use `parseInt()` to turn them into numbers.

```
data = [
  { type: "type1", value: 60 },
  { type: "type2", value: 38 },
  { type: "type3", value: 4 },
  { type: "type4", value: 5 },
  { type: "type5", value: 8 },
  { type: "type6", value: 2 },
];

let max = 0;

data.forEach(obj => {
  if (obj.value > max) max = obj.value
});
```

Comment: Why do you use `map` when you neither return a mapped value, nor use the mapped array.?`forEach` would make more sense.

Comment: `forEach()` is actually quite slower compared to `map()`. If you can use `map()`, it's best to use it. See more about this topic here: https://medium.com/@JeffLombardJr/understanding-foreach-map-filter-and-find-in-javascript-f91da93b9f2c

Comment: That's actually not true. `map` is 60-80% slower than `forEach` on Chrome 83. See this [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-map-x3jf)

Comment: Oh ok then... That's for the clarification . Will also edit my answer