# How does this sorting function in js is working?

Tags: javascript, next.js

In **Next.js** site (here https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/implement-getstaticprops), this example :

```
import path from 'path'
import matter from 'gray-matter'

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), 'posts')

export function getSortedPostsData() {
  // Get file names under /posts
  const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory)
  const allPostsData = fileNames.map(fileName => {
    // Remove ".md" from file name to get id
    const id = fileName.replace(/\.md$/, '')

    // Read markdown file as string
    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, fileName)
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, 'utf8')

    // Use gray-matter to parse the post metadata section
    const matterResult = matter(fileContents)

    // Combine the data with the id
    return {
      id,
      ...matterResult.data
    }
  })
  // Sort posts by date
  return allPostsData.sort(({ date: a }, { date: b }) => {
    if (a < b) {
      return 1
    } else if (a > b) {
      return -1
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  })
}
```

In this example the return value of function **getSortedPostsData()** is a sorted list of **allPostsData**. Posts are sorted on the basis of date.

**My question is how  the array is being sorted ?**

The **sort function** is taking two arguments **{date:a} , {date:b}**.
Is it automatically converting the arguments to **Date Object** as the **a.date and b.date** are strings

Comment: They are destructuring the `date` property of 2 objects being compared to `a` and `b` variables. Can you please add the sample values for `allPostsData` with the `date` property?

Comment: "*Is it automatically converting the arguments to Date Object as the a.date and b.date are strings*" no, why would it? There is nothing telling JS that the strings represent dates. They are just compared as strings.

Comment: @adiga  here they are : `{
  id: 'ssg-ssr',
  title: 'When to Use Static Generation v.s. Server-side Rendering',
  date: '2020-01-02'
} {
  id: 'pre-rendering',
  title: 'Two Forms of Pre-rendering',
  date: '2020-01-01'
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation) shows which sorting algorithm is used for each situation.

It is **not** automatically converting the arguments to Dates. That must be done beforehand. If you say that Date a and b are strings, they will be compared [lexicographicaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863092/why-is-string-11-less-than-string-3) according to the callback provided to the sort function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think you are right. They are comparing **lexicographicaly**