# reactive form custom validator get called but not displaying the error in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

The custom validator get called but errors are not displaying.

**The JS portion of the form is:**

```
this.form = this.fb.group(
      {
        article:'',
        onlyNotInProposal: false,
        ruleEnabled: false,
        minimum: [
          {
            value: 0,
            disabled: true,

          }
        ],
        maximum: [
          {
            value: null,
            disabled: true
          }]
      },
      { validators: stockThresholdValidator }
    );
```

**The validator code is:**

```
import { FormGroup, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

import { greaterThanValidator } from '@g3p/shared/validators/greater-than/greater-than.validator';

export const stockThresholdValidator: ValidatorFn = (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
  if (!formGroup.controls.ruleEnabled) {
    return null;
  }
  if (formGroup.controls.ruleEnabled.value) {
    return greaterThanValidator('minimum', 'maximum')(formGroup);
  }
  return null;
};
```

**greaterThanValidator code:**

```
import { AbstractControl, FormGroup, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function greaterThanValidator(minControlName: string, maxControlName: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const min: AbstractControl = formGroup.get(minControlName);
    const max: AbstractControl = formGroup.get(maxControlName);
    if (!min || !max) {
      return { missingControl: true };
    }
    if ((min.value !== 0 && !min.value) || (max.value !== 0 && !max.value)) {
      return { missingValue: true };
    }
    if (isNaN(min.value) || isNaN(max.value)) {
      return { onlyNumbersRequired: true };
    }
    if (min.value >= max.value) {
      return { greaterThan: true };
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

I have spent a lot of time but I am not able to figure out what is wrong. If someone knows then please let me know. Thank you

Comment: The question is, what does greaterThanValidator() return exactly?

Comment: Can you give a minimal example on stackblitz  which reproduces the issue?

Comment: I see the code you've shared works fine. I am guessing there might a problem in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `ruleEnabled: false` which prevents `greaterThanValidator()` from being called. However, if you did set it `true` later in the template. There could be an issue if you forgot to add `type=number` for `minimum` and `maximum` fields. By default, you will get back strings so the below check

```
if (min.value >= max.value) {
```

will be comparing strings [lexicographically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863092/why-is-string-11-less-than-string-3), not numerically.

I've created a sample app with the information you provided and see that the code works fine.

[Sample App onStackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1wwqx?file=src%2Fmain.ts%3AL62)

### Demo

[image]